# Callback issue with getSteam iOS sdk

Tags: ios, swift, getstream-io

I think something wrong with the iOS SDK of getStream. I m not getting any callback on following , unfollowing and checking if user is following someone.For all these three case callback is not coming. 
Even in the sample app given by stream is not working for these case. 
Below is the code from ProfileViewController from sample app.
Rest of the sample app working fine.
Url of the sample is : https://github.com/GetStream/swift-activity-feed

```
User.current?.isFollow(toTarget: flatFeedPresenter.flatFeed.feedId) { [weak self] in
        button.isEnabled = true

        if let error = $2 {
            self?.showErrorAlert(error)
        } else {
            button.isSelected = $0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug, inside `isFollow` the user flat feed is deallocating after the request. Please check the new version v.1.0.11.